# How to display one row of data grid in ASP.NET c# using WCF

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, silverlight

I am working in silverlight application using WCF. I want to show specific row from the database in the data grid.

I found e.result BUT this will show the whole from DB.

Below is my code:

```
public TrainingBatchesUsersResults(int TraineeID)//, int TrainingProgramID, int >ReadyContainerID, int TrainingBatch, int ReadyContainerItemID)
{
     InitializeComponent();
     XraySimulatorWCFServices.XraySimulatorServiceClient XrayClient =new XraySimulatorWCFServices.XraySimulatorServiceClient();

     XrayClient.GetTrainingBatchesUsersResultsCompleted += new EventHandler&lt;
     XraySimulatorWCFServices.GetTrainingBatchesUsersResultsCompletedEventArgs&gt;(DisplayTrainingBatchesUsersResults);

     XrayClient.GetTrainingBatchesUsersResultsAsync(TraineeID);

     LayoutRoot.UpdateLayout();
}

private void DisplayTrainingBatchesUsersResults(object sender, XraySimulatorWCFServices.GetTrainingBatchesUsersResultsCompletedEventArgs e)
{
       dgvResult.ItemsSource = e.Result;
     dgvResult.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
}
```

Comment: instead of `itemsSource`, have  you tried with `DataSource` property of datagrid view

Comment: There is no datasource in silverlight!!

Comment: You should return only one single result there

Comment: I need to return one row which is depend on the id!!

Answer (score 0):

Just set your `ItemsSource` to the single row you want to show then, rather than the whole results collection. For example `dgvResult.ItemsSource=e.Result.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.Id==theIdYouWantToShow)`

BUT what you really want is to do this further up the chain so that you only RETURN the single row you want, rather than return the whole table and reduce that set on the client. 
Your call `XrayClient.GetTrainingBatchesUsersResultsAsync(TraineeID);` presumably is returning all your rows, why not have a new method that only returns the single result you're interested in?